# Calling method after view has loaded

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

My iPhone app allows for users to type in their usernames and passwords so that they can login. When they login once, their usernames and passwords are saved so that users don't have to type it in again. My problem is, when the app starts again, it immediately starts logging them in, leaving the interface completely black. How would I go about calling my login method AFTER all the UI methods are loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your login code in the [viewDidLoad](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) method of your view controller.  Alternatively, do your login in a background thread so that it doesn't freeze the UI which is occuring on the main thread.